# Error:No cached version listing for io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+ available for offline mode

Tags: android, android-studio, twitter-fabric

This problem occurred when updated android studio and import old project in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reinstall Fabric android plugin. You can get it here: https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' } added buildscript repositories.